# libcURL Post Confusion

Tags: c, libcurl

I am trying to do a simple post using libcURL. I noticed that if I define my data as

char const data[] = "Some data";

It does not POST.

If I use char const *data = "Some data";

It does POST.

The main issue is [] vs *. Since an array is a pointer I don't understand why it won't post using the array style.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: If you don't present more complete examples it is impossible to tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libcurl will POST the data you pass to it, with for example the [CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPOSTFIELDS) option. It does not distinguish between a char array and a pointer to data as long as you make sure you pass it on correctly.

A very simple post example can be found here: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simplepost.html